# Update query on Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I maintain an application developed in Access. And I have to implement an update query, but I'm quite stuck at the moment and I don't understand why.

Basically, the query must update a record from table X following another record from that same table, but the query I wrote does nothing, I did test separately the update and the select and they both work, but together, no.

I hope some of you may found my problem.

Here is the query I wrote (I did remove some fields to avoid to be too long, and of course, the query you will see was tested to be sure it was not the missing fields the issue)

```
UPDATE 
    TABLE_X AS recordToUpdate,
    (
    SELECT 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.[NUM-GrpHdr], 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.[NUM-LOT], 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.[SINGLE-SCENARIO], 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.EqvtAmt, 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.EqvtAmtCur, 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.EqvtAmtCurTft, 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.XchgRateInfExchangeRate, 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.XchgRateInfRateType, 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.XchgRateInfContractId, 
        DUP_C2B_From_CPL.ChqTp

        FROM DUP_C2B_From_CPL
    ) AS originalRecord

SET
    recordToUpdate.EqvtAmt = originalRecord.EqvtAmt, 
    recordToUpdate.EqvtAmtCur = originalRecord.EqvtAmtCur, 
    recordToUpdate.EqvtAmtCurTft = originalRecord.EqvtAmtCurTft, 
    recordToUpdate.XchgRateInfExchangeRate = originalRecord.XchgRateInfExchangeRate, 
    recordToUpdate.XchgRateInfRateType = originalRecord.XchgRateInfRateType, 
    recordToUpdate.XchgRateInfContractId = originalRecord.XchgRateInfContractId, 
    recordToUpdate.ChqTp = originalRecord.ChqTp 

WHERE
    recordToUpdate.[SINGLE-SCENARIO] = 112811
```

**DUP_C2B_From_CPL** here is a subQuery that is retrieving the record I'm interested in so I can take its values to update the other one.

In the last WHERE closure, I hardcoded the id for more readability for you (and yes it exists :))

And also the designer is rendering correctly, so no error on this side. But as I said, it seems that it is not updating anything.

Don't hesitate to tell me if you nee more information.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a JOIN between `recordToUpdate` and `originalRecord`? (i.e. I think you need one for the query to be updateable)

Comment: *"it seems that it is not updating anything."* - what happens when you run the query? Does Access say "0 record(s) updated" or is there another message?

Comment: Hi Andre, I can't do a JOIN because there is no unique identifier between them. I first try to do it but I was stuck on the ON because it could result on updating the wrong record.

@Edit:
" what happens when you run the query? Does Access say "0 record(s) updated" or is there another message?"
When I run the query, it shows me all the columns that should be updated, but without data in it. ANd when I refresh the table, the record that should be updated is not.

Comment: *When I run the query, it shows me all the columns that should be updated, but without data in it.* -- To actually execute an action query you must click the "Execute" or "Run" button (red exclamation mark), not the Datasheet button.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below.

```
UPDATE 
  Table1 AS t1 
  INNER JOIN Table1 AS t2 
    ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field2
SET 
  T1.Field1 = t2.field1
```

If there is not any join then you can try like below

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 , Table1 t2
SET T1.Field1 = t2.field1
where t1.field1 = 'aa' and t2.field1 = 'bb'
```

Comment: Thank you Jatin for you input, but it does not work, it is still the same result, nothing is changed, I did try to adapt a SELECT from your second query, and I have the right result, but with the update, no.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason, I had to restart my laptop, and the query is now working.

Thank you for your help.